# Django - admin.py for multiple apps in a single django project

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a Django project that has 2 apps - a blog app and a tutorials app. I just completed the blog app and it has the `admin.py` for registering the models like so:

```
admin.site.register(Blog, BlogAdmin)
admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

I just started working on the tutorials app and wrote the models and created the `admin.py` within it. It looks as follows:

```
admin.site.register(Tutorial, tutorialAdmin)
admin.site.register(tutType, tutTypeAdmin)
```

The models have been imported. However, when I run `python manage.py syncdb` and then `python manage.py runserver`, I do not find the new models in the admin section of the site (`127.0.0.1:8000/admin`).

Should I move the `admin.py` outside both the apps and make it a single file which registers all the models of the different apps? Or is there some other step that I am missing out on?

Comment: I do not think every app needs an admin.py.

Comment: @iMom0 - Ok.. However, for both the blog and the tutorial apps, there'll be more than one person making contributions. Therefore, I thought having an admin login section was the way forward, where the contributors could log in and add posts or tutorials as per the permissions assigned to that person.

Comment: @i.h4d35 It's normal to have an admin.py for every app you want to show up. Have you added your tutorial app to your INSTALLED_APPS settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@i.h4d35 I think DivinusVox is right. Try to add your new app in INSTALLED_APPS in the settings.py and it should be solved. Please check admin info from [Django official website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/).